# Find joint bivariate distribution using double integral (Wackerly 5.5a)

Tags: probability, integration

This is problem 5.5a from Mathematical Statistics with Applications 7th Edition - Wackerly et al. The background to the problem is that we have a tank which is filled with gas once a week. $Y_1$ is the proportion of the capacity of the tank that is available after it is stocked at the beginning of the week. $Y_2$ denotes the proportion of the capacity of the tank that is sold during the week.

The bivariate probability density function $f(y_1,y_2)$ is given by the following:
$$
    f(y_1,y_2)=
    \begin{cases}
      3y_1, & 0\leq y_2 \leq y_1 \leq 1 \\
      0, & elsewhere
    \end{cases} 
$$

Using this information we need to calculate the joint bivariate distribution $F(y_1,y_2) = P(Y_1 \leq y_1, Y_2 \leq y_2)$ for $F(1/2, 1/3)$

A 3D graph (left) and a 2D cross section of the problem can be seen below (where the green lines indicate the limit reference):

[3D graph and 2D cross section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8XCA.jpg)

Now we can calculate joint bivariate function using the following formula:
$$
    F(y_1,y_2) = \int_{b}^{a}\int_{d}^{c} 3y_1 \,dy_2\,dy_1
$$

Here is where I'm having some difficulty. I'm not sure what the limits for the integration should be. My attempt yielded the following:

$$
    F(1/2,1/3) = \int_{0}^{1/3}\int_{0}^{y_1} 3y_1 \,dy_2\,dy_1 = 1/27 = 0.0370
$$

This makes sense to me since the point of intersection between $y_1$ and $y_2$ is the area under the line that is less than 1/3. However, the solution manual gives the following:

$$
    F(1/2,1/3) = \int_{0}^{1/2}\int_{0}^{1/3} 3y_1 \,dy_1\,dy_2 = 0.1065
$$

If someone could kindly shed some light into where I'm going wrong, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both you and your solution manual are incorrect. It turns out the solution manual's final answer is correct, but note that the integral in your manual cannot be correct since

$$\int_0^{1/2}\int_0^{1/3}3y_1dy_1dy_2=\frac{1}{12}\neq 0.1065.$$
A quick sketch can help solve it:
[image]

The blue region is the support, and the the black trapezoidal region is your region of integration, which evaluates to

$$F(1/2,1/3)=\int_0^{1/3}\int_{y_2}^{1/2}3y_1dy_1dy_2=\frac{23}{216}\approx 0.1065.$$

If you wanted to reverse the order of integration, you would compute it as

$$F(1/2,1/3)=\int_0^{1/3}\int_{0}^{y_1}3y_1dy_2dy_1+\int_{1/3}^{1/2}\int_{0}^{1/3}3y_1dy_2dy_1=\frac{23}{216}\approx 0.1065.$$

Comment: That makes sense, thank you.

Comment: of course, no prob